# Multiple volume notifications on xfce4 caused by UnknownMethod error

Tags: notifications, d-bus, xfce

The visible part of the bug is that I get multiple notifications when changing the volume:

[image: Multiple volume notifications]

The symptoms look identical to that of [a question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035378/xfce-multiple-volume-notifications) but, since it might be a different cause, and I am not actually using Ubuntu, I am opening a new question.

After some tinkering around, I noticed something strange. When calling the `Notify` method of the `xorg.freedesktop.Notifications` D-Bus service, I can display a notification, but I get an error in return:

[image: Calling the Notify methods works but return an error]

Since I am using `d-feet` to browse the D-Bus services and inspecting the method signature, I am pretty I am using the right argument types (I get more specific errors otherwise). I get the same error when using `notify-send`:

```
~% notify-send a                                                              
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Notify" with signature "susssasa{sv}i" on interface "org.freedesktop.Notifications" doesn't exist
```

At least one other person has encountered the same issue around the same time: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/pygobject-desktop-notifications-stopped-working-4175710943/

When comparing with a Xubuntu 20.04 without the bug, I see that it is supposed to return the id of the notification, which can then be used as the `replacedid` parameter to update the notification. That would explain why `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin` cannot update the first notification and instead open new ones.

I am using Debian testing (bookworm) with the latest updates, with `xfce4=4.16`, `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin=0.4.3-1`, `xfce4-notifyd=0.6.3-1` and `dbus=1.14.0-1`. Also note that `xorg.freedesktop.Notifications` is actually provided by `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service`:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
SystemdService=xfce4-notifyd.service
```

I guess it might plausibly be a bug of `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin`, `dbus`, `xfce4-notifyd`, or, more likely, my configuration. What can I do to get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 1):

I did not think it would be enough to find a solution, but just looking at D-Bus logs got me on the right track.

So, I ran the following command while opening a notification from `d-feet`.

```
dbus-monitor >log
```

In the log, I was able to find the corresponding exchange:

```
method call time=1656781561.510107 sender=:1.75 -> destination=:1.48 serial=325 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "Test"
   uint32 0
   string "computer"
   string "Title"
   string "Body"
   array [
   ]
   array [
   ]
   int32 1
error time=1656781561.510300 sender=:1.61 -> destination=:1.75 error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod reply_serial=325
   string "Method "Notify" with signature "susssasa{sv}i" on interface "org.freedesktop.Notifications" doesn't exist
"
```

It contains the same information I had, *except that it also includes ids for the communicating services* . You can see that the method call was sent from `:1.75` (`d-tree` itself) to `:1.48` (the D-Bus service for `xfce4-notifyd` as per `d-tree`, as show in the screenshot below).

[image: The D-Bus service provided by xfce4-notifyd in d-tree]

*However*, the error comes from `:1.61`. Looking in `d-tree`, I notice the `eavesdrop=true`, which hints to me that another service did something to the method call.

[image: The other unexpected service in d-tree]

Looking around, I end up on [a post about deprecating eavesdropping in session.conf of D-bus](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/-/merge_requests/52). Scanning my system, I locate `/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf`, apply the following patch and restart my session. Now, everything is fine!

```
-    <allow send_destination="*" eavesdrop="true"/>
+    <allow send_destination="*" eavesdrop="false"/>
     <!-- Allow everything to be received -->
-    <allow eavesdrop="true"/>
+    <allow eavesdrop="false"/>
```

My understanding is that the original service did its work properly, but another service tried to handle it, failed because it did not have the proper `Notify` method (or the wrong signature). I have no idea where this eavesdropping comes from, and a proper fix would imply identifying it. However, the workaround seems to solve my initial issue.

---

**Edit:** I have found the culprit by running `grep -r freedesktop.Notifications ~/.local`. It turns out I had not updated the [Discover overlay](https://github.com/trigg/Discover), which is not managed by `apt`. After running `pip install --upgrade discover-overlay`, and reverting my changes to `/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf`, everything is back to normal!